# Browse old versions of iTunes playlists via Time Machine?

Tags: itunes, time-machine, playlist

I would like to look at some of my iTunes playlists and see their contents some months or a year ago. I know I can restore the whole iTunes library, then ask iTunes to open a non-default library when I launch it and finally export the old version of the playlist but that is quite a task, especially when I probably want to do it for a handful of playlists and many times for each playlist.

For example the Contacts app allows you to search for something and then enter Time Machine and see what that search would have yielded for result in older versions of the database. Does iTunes offer something similar?